# How to detect the shortcut combination CTRL + Key in python curses

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I have been reading the documentation on curses in Python  but I cannot figure it out how to detect the combinations like CTRL-S, or CTRL-A, or ALT-X, or CMD+A (in macOS), etc.
Anyone knows how to do it?

Someone mentioned user ord(), but I cannot find the number that CTRL returns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to see the Ctrl key by itself, you have to work at a layer lower than Python works at.  It's a modifier key, which means it modifies the action of the other key you press at the same time.  It doesn't generate a character all by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windows.getkey` returns `^A` for CTRL-A, wich is a special character with ord 1. Simlarly, CTRL-E will return `^E` which has ord(5).

Try this for seeing the strings that `getkey` returns when you press a key. Note that some keys (Cursor keys for instance) will return a mutlti-byte string.

```
from curses import wrapper

def main(stdscr):
    while True:
        key = stdscr.getkey()
        stdscr.clear()
        stdscr.addstr(1,0, "Key pressed is '{}' (ord {})".format(key, ord(key[0])))
        stdscr.refresh()
        if ord(key) == 24: # CTRL-X
            break

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly what I need it!!

Comment: To anyone seeing this question and in need of detect CTRL+S, CTRL-Q and other keys that are not detected by the code added by @treuss, I have to add that those keys are intercepted by the terminal, and the only way to detect them is to use the raw() and noraw() calls